# How to write a short array with an specifed index range using Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I have done this in matlab, for example

```
yArray [200 500] = xArray [900 1200]
```

so this way

`yArray [1 499]` and `yArray[1201 inf]`remain the same 
I have tried using Arrays.CopyOfRange, but it seems to write data from start to an index bound.Is it possible to do `yArray[200 500] = 0` too?

Comment: Java doesn't have that syntax. You can't set a range of indexes like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy a range of values from one array to another, use [`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-)

```
System.arraycopy(xArray, 900, yArray, 200, 300);
```

To fill a range of values with a single value, use [`Arrays.fill`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill-int:A-int-int-int-)

```
Arrays.fill(yArray, 200, 500, 0);
```